# Commutation relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, commutator

Given that the Hamiltonian for Muonium spin in zero magnetic field is

$$\hat{H} = a \vec I \cdot \vec J$$

where $\vec I$ is the spin of a muon, and *$\vec J$* is the spin of the electron, what is the commutation relation between $[H,I^2]$ ?

What I initially thought was that the electron spin could be written as 
$$\vec J = (\sigma_x , \sigma_y , \sigma_z ) $$
where $\sigma$ are the Pauli matrices. However I'm not sure if that is right because I have no idea how to do the same for muon spin $\vec I$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you are actively working on the problem I will offer a series of hints. Please comment if you need further guidance.

**Hint 1**: Muonium is a bound state of $\mu^+ e^-$. Note that they are both spin 1/2 particles, and have their own Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_\mu$ and $\mathcal{H}_e$. **Your** operator $\hat{H}$ lives in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_\mu \otimes \mathcal{H}_e$. (If this notation frightens you, don't worry I won't use it but I mention it if you're curious about the machinery).

First let us write

$$ H = a\sum_{i=k}^3 \hat{I}_k \hat{J}_k  \equiv a\sum_{i=k}^3 \hat{S}_k^{(\mu)} \hat{S}^{(e)}_k $$

where I just just relabeled the spin operators in a notation that I think may be familiar to you. I haven't actually *done anything* yet.

**Hint 2:** An implication of the muon and the electron living in two different hilbert spaces is that they each separately obey their **own commutation relations** and are completely independent of one another. In the language of commutators this means that

$$[\hat{S}^{(e)}_i, \hat{S}^{(e)}_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk} \hat{S}^{(e)}_k $$

$$[\hat{S}^{(\mu)}_i, \hat{S}^{(\mu)}_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk} \hat{S}^{(\mu)}_k $$

$$[\hat{S}^{(e)}_i,\hat{S}^{(\mu)}_j] = 0$$

If you need more hints just shoot me a comment.

Comment: If I substituted the $\hat S$ with the corresponding Matrix that shows that $[H,\vec I] = 0$, that is what I am getting

Comment: can you type out your work

Comment: $[H,\vec I] = \sum_{i=1}^3 \hat S_i^{(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(e)} \hat S_i^{(\mu)} - \sum_{i=1}^3 \hat S_i^{(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(e)}$ so expand the sum and sub in $$S_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}}$$, $$S_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&i \\ -i&0 \end{pmatrix}}$$ and $$S_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix}}$$ and that should give zero

Comment: I meant in your question so everybody can track your progress

Comment: Is the below answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

$$[H,I^2] = \sum_{i=1}^3 \hat S_i^{(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(e)} \hat S_i^{2(\mu)} - \sum_{i=1}^3 \hat S_i^{2(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(\mu)} \hat S_i^{(e)}$$ 
 
Expand the sum, and sum in the matrices
$$S_1 = \frac{\hbar} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
,
$$S_2 = \frac{\hbar} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&i \\ -i&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$S_3 = \frac{\hbar} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Let's look when $i=1$, the equation will be 
$$\hat S_1^{(\mu)} \hat S_1^{(e)} \hat S_1^{2(\mu)} - \hat S_1^{2(\mu)} \hat S_1^{(\mu)} \hat S_1^{(e)}$$ 
 In the first term sub in the matrix and for simplicity lets make $\hbar = 1$ 
$$\frac{1} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix} . \frac{1} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix} . \Biggl(\frac{1} {2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}\Biggr)^2$$
Because these matrices are  Hermitian $\hat S_1^{2(\mu)}$ will just become the identity matrix and so is $\hat S_1^{(\mu)} \hat S_1^{(e)}$ so the end result for the first term will be $\frac{1}{16}$, doing the same for the second term we will get $\frac{1}{16}$, then subtracting both sides we get zero. Doing the same for $i=2,3$ we will get zero as well, so this Hamiltonian commute with the muon spin.